# How to count a non-consecutive winning streak?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a counter of the maximum daily "win streak" of a specific activity.  However, in any given day it's perfectly reasonable to have not attempted the activity in question at all.  Weekends in particular are the usual culprit.  So I need to be able to count the largest "winning streak" that can have days which are skipped.

Data example:

| Date | Win |
| --- | --- |
| Mon, Sep 12 | FALSE |
| Tue, Sep 13 | TRUE |
| Wed, Sep 14 | FALSE |
| Thu, Sep 15 | TRUE |
| Fri, Sep 16 | TRUE |
| Sat, Sep 17 | - |
| Sun, Sep 18 | - |
| Mon, Sep 19 | TRUE |

So in this example, the largest win streak is 3.  Saturday and Sunday are ignored as nothing happened those days.

I currently am using [a formula at this page](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/longest-winning-losing-streak-formula-google-sheets/) and it works but does not ignore days without activity:

```
=sortn(frequency(if((Q2:Q>0)*len(Q2:Q),row(Q2:Q)),if((Q2:Q>0)*len(Q2:Q),,row(Q2:Q))),1,0,1,0)
```

How can I modify this formula to ignore "null" days, or use a different single-formula (no helper columns etc.) approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `frequency()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( max( frequency(if(B2:B = true, row(B2:B)), if(B2:B = false, row(B2:B))) ) )`